# Initial value in a TextFormField (Flutter) coming from a Future (Firebase)

Tags: firebase, flutter, future

folks.

I am trying to set an initialValue of a `TextFormField` from a String that comes from Firebase Firestore, so it is a Future. But i just can't make it work!

I have written a simplified code of my problem and is available on dartPad:

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/0649b56c10041ca7e6ab4440e7564dea

How should I do this correctly? Should I use a `Future.then()` instead of the `FutureBuilder`? Should I use a controller, instead of setting the initialValue? Any form I try, it ends up not working...

Comment: i have changed the code from dartpad (from gist). I noted that if i changed the position of FutureBuilder the code works... I am not sure why...

Comment: Please also include code in your question. Links can break over time and that would make the question worthless to future readers. You may also include a link but in the question is super important.

Answer (score 0):

The text field will be empty until the task is complete but this works fine:

```
final _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    asyncTask()
  }

void asyncTask() async{
   //do work
   setState(() {
        _textEditingController.text = workResult;
      });
}
//in build method
TextFormField(
   controller: _emailtextEditingController,
   .
   .
   .
),
```

Comment: This does not work on current flutter stable anymore..